# Significant figures in scientific notation

Tags: notation

If I want to express a number in scientific notation, e.g. 0.0068

according to my textbook this is $$6.8 \times 10^{-3}$$
I'm wondering would $$68 \times 10^{-4}$$ be equivalent? 0.0068
has got two significant figures, and therefore the
coefficient should have two significant figures as well,
but isn't this true for both 6.8 and 68?

Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The first is scientific notation, the second is not, but it is understood and possible to write the number that way.

Comment: Adding to what Triatticus said, as of my experience it is also common to move the decimal point left or right one digit if this allows for the use of an SI-prefix. Like writing 68 cm or 0.68m instead of $6.8 \times 10^{-1}$m.

Comment: More on [significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+significant+figures).